# Rails FactoryGirl inside app in development env

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I'm trying to use FactoryGirl gem inside my App in development mode (it's for mailer tests [more](https://github.com/glebm/rails_email_preview/issues/66#issuecomment-215954485)) with [rails_email_preview](https://github.com/glebm/rails_email_preview) gem.

It works but only on initial page load, after reloading/refreshing the page I get following error:

```
Factory not registered: order
```

where `order` is name of factory.

Here is my code (it is a dummy app for my Rails Engine):

**spec/dummy/app/mailer_previews/mymodule/order_mailer_preview.rb**

```
Dir[Mymodule::Core::Engine.root.join('spec', 'factories', '*')].each do |f|
  require_dependency f
end

module Mymodule
class OrderMailerPreview
  def confirmation_email

    o = FactoryGirl.create(:order)

    OrderMailer.confirmation_email(o)
  end
end
end
```

Of course my factories works without any problem in test environment.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

```
p FactoryGirl.factories
```

returns (after page reload)

```
#<FactoryGirl::Registry:0x007ff2c9dd29d0 @name="Factory", @items={}>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my issue was connected with **Devise** gem.
I have code in my initializer which clears factories on each reload because of devise issue (described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363471/could-not-find-a-valid-mapping-for-user-only-on-second-and-successive-t)).
This code runs only when there are some factories, so not on the first request.

The solution was to change my **config/initializers/devise.rb** file from:

```
ActionDispatch::Callbacks.after do
  # Reload the factories
  return unless (Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.test?)

  unless FactoryGirl.factories.blank? # first init will load factories, this should only run on subsequent reloads
    FactoryGirl.factories.clear
    FactoryGirl.find_definitions
  end
end
```

to:

```
ActionDispatch::Callbacks.before do
  # Reload the factories
  return unless (Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.test?)

  FactoryGirl.definition_file_paths = [Mymodule::Core::Engine.root.join('spec', 'factories')]

  # first init will load factories, this should only run on subsequent reloads
  unless FactoryGirl.factories.blank?
    FactoryGirl.factories.clear
    FactoryGirl.sequences.clear
    FactoryGirl.find_definitions
  end
end
```

Note: `before` instead of `after` callback and custom `FactoryGirl.definition_file_paths` definition before `find_definitions` is executed.

Each time I try to use `after` hook I get Devise error on first call.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to call `FactoryGirl.find_definitions` to load factory girl in development.

```
require 'factory_girl'
FactoryGirl.find_definitions
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: I've tried it  but with no luck. Still it works after initial load and breaks on reload with `Factory no registered` error.